# How to generate a collection using for comprehension (no yield)

Tags: scala

I was wondering this a long time ago. Scala promotes immutability (which I perfectly adore). However a big problem comes with for loop. The common way to do this is to use a for comprehension and use `yield`, which I tend to do whenever I can. However, there are circumstances that I can't use `yield`. How do I generate a collection without `yield` and assign it to a variable?

For example:

```
  def dirRun(dir: String) = {
    //change this part
    println("Start dir run!")
    val companyList: ListBuffer[(Int, Doc)] = ListBuffer()

    val file = new File(dir)
    for (f <- file.listFiles if f.getName.endsWith(".txt")) {
      println(f.getAbsolutePath)
      companyList += run(f)
    }
    companyList
  }
```

This is a directory run method that calls a `run()` method that processes on a single file. Directory run scan through the folder, and call `run()`. `run()` returns a list and the program appends it to a list. The ultimate goal is to be able to kill the mutable `ListBuffer` and assign the for-loop to a variable, but I don't know how.

This is the signiture for `run()` method: `def run(file: File):(Int, Doc)` (It returns a tuple).

How do I fix this?

---

I argue that this question is still relevant to people who didn't understand concepts such as `yield` or `map`. I honestly read a book for Scala (but it didn't say much about `yield` and `map`)

Comment: By the way, it's often considered better style (and also generally safer) to use a `var` with an immutable List which you `:+=` to rather than a `val` with a mutable data structure. Also, `val companyList = ListBuffer.empty[(Int, Doc)]` I think is nicer than repeating the `ListBuffer` part twice. Futhermore, if you must use a mutable data structure, make sure to convert it to an immutable one before returning it to the caller: `companyList.toList`, or at least cast to `Seq` so the caller wouldn't see a mutable return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map`:

```
val files = for (f <- file.listFiles if f.getName.endsWith(".txt")) yield f
files.map(f => println(f.getAbsolutePath); run(f))
```

Comment: wait..you can have two arguments in one `map` function?

Comment: I think it should be `files.map { f => println(f.getAbsolutePath); run(f) }` but maybe the provided syntax is equivalent (but apparently confusing).

Comment: @WindDweller - There's only one argument `f`. The body is the `println` statement followed by the application of `run`, and returns that value. Admittedly putting effects in a projection is quite ugly.

Comment: @ErikAllik So basically `map` maps every element in files to two functions. If I may ask, does map always map to every element? What if you only want to map to a few with certain conditions?

Comment: @Lee when you say effects, do you mean the `println()` ?

Comment: @WindDweller: no, it's just a lambda with 2 expressions in its body, not 2 lambdas.

Comment: @WindDweller - Yes, arguments to `map` should ideally be pure but `println` prints to the console as a side-effect.

Comment: And you don't have to have the `println` within the map... you can just print the resulting collection after `map` is complete.

Comment: @ErikAllik I understand that `side effect` should be delayed as much as possible, but sometimes I want to know the processing status in the middle (because `dirRun` goes through 5000 files)...if this is bad, how to do the status reporting correctly in Scala?

Answer (score 7):

Um, why can't you use yield?  Yield is a great way to do this:

```
val companyList = 
  for (f <- file.listFiles if f.getName.endsWith(".txt")) yield {
    println(f.getAbsolutePath)
    run(f)
  }
```

The thing following `yield` is just an expression.  In this case, it's a a block.   A block after a `yield` is the same as any block: you can do anything you want in it.  And then the last expression in the block is the thing that's put in the final collection.

Comment: I didn't know I can put two arguments inside `yield`